# Changing Type with ReSharper Search By Pattern

Tags: c#, resharper

**Issue:** I keep setting a dependency on ILogger but really need ILoggerFactory

**Solution:** Have ReSharper identify that I should use ILoggerFactory and fix my code.

**What I Have Tried**
[image]

**The Error:** i am getting is "$ILoggerFactory$ is not declared"
the error goes away if i place the $ILoggerFactory$ placeholder in the search pattern but that is not what i am looking to do.

I have declared both ILogger and ILoggerFactory an explicitly set the types including namespace I want them to be.

**The Question:** how to i change the type using this feature?

**PS:** the overall idea for this pattern is that it will identify any peram in the ctor that is `ILogger` and suggest to change it to `ILoggerFacotry` regardless of number of ctor perams and then do so and replace the set of `_logger` with the `factory.Create<T>` method.

Comment: Will it help if you change '$ILoggerFactory$' to '$ILogger$Factory' in the replace pattern?

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin it could but then i would only have one strong type ref to the specific interface, the resulting logger factory could (tho not likely) end up being a different log factory. not a bad ideal and i will give that a go

Comment: Unfortunately, the Replace pattern can't have a placeholder which does not exist in the Search pattern, so I do not see another way to get the same result.